# What is the correct query statement?

Tags: mysql

Problem: Display the name of students that are enrolled under Program IT, CS & MIS and the corresponding Head of each Program.

I tried this code but it does not work...

```
SELECT s.lname,s.fname,P.Head FROM STUDENT AS s,
PROGRAM AS P WHERE Program IN ('IT','CS','MIS');
```

I expect the output will be in one table containing the names of the students that are enrolled in the Program and the Head of each program.

[image: Table details]

Comment: can you give us table structure, Also what is expected output and output you are getting

Comment: Is program a table name?  Program IN ('IT','CS','MIS'); looks like program should be changed for the column name in program, Don't use implicit join use explicit joins, And do add table definitions an sample data as text.

Comment: @RahulSingh image has been attach....

Comment: @P.Salmon, yes program is a table containing the programs and heads...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the tables:

```
SELECT s.fname, s.lname, P.Head 
FROM STUDENT AS s INNER JOIN PROGRAM AS P 
ON s.Program = P.ProgramName
WHERE s.program IN ('IT','CS','MIS')
```

Comment: the P.Program is unknown in ON clause..:(

Comment: In the image you posted Program is a column of the table Program or not?

Comment: See my edited answer. If the name of the column in student is also ProgramName change s.program to s.programname.

Answer (score 0):

Try using join will resolve your problem.

```
SELECT s.lname,s.fname,p.Head
FROM STUDENT s
JOIN PROGRAM p
    ON a.program=b.program
WHERE s.program IN ('IT','CS','MIS');
```

Answer (score 0):

Join Will resolve your problem

```
    SELECT t1.requredColumnName1,t1.requredCName2,t2.requredName
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.columnName=t2.columnName
WHERE t1.columnName IN ('param1','param2','param3');
```

For your Problem

```
SELECT t1.lname,t1.fname,t2.Head
FROM STUDENT t1
JOIN PROGRAM t2
    ON t1.program=t2.program
WHERE t1.program IN ('IT','CS','MIS');
```